# Section numbering in document but NOT in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

How to make section numbering of preface in document but NOT display in table of contents

[image]
[image]

Comment: This might depend on the used class, so please add a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050) to your question. Also IMHO it is a bad idea to remove the numbering from ToC, as it helps orienting in a document a lot.

Comment: Did the solution work ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way: put in your preamble

```
  \newcommand{\shadowsection}[1]{
    \stepcounter{section}
    \section*{\thesection\quad #1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
  }
```

Then when typing your document

```
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}
\shadowsection{Section in preface 1}
\shadowsection{Section in preface 2}
```

will give you the output : 
[image: table of contents] 
[image: preface]

Comment: This would require to change a complete document. There might be better ways, but as long as the OP doesn't say which packages and which class he uses, there is no way one could provide a clean solution, imho.

Comment: I agree. But since he was only asking for preface, maybe he wouldn't have to write the whole document again.